# MySQL select all user ids where 'xyz' is not a value in a column of another table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables, a user table and a houses table. The users just has a bunch of ids (minimal example), something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
    id character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

the houses table has 3 columns, and id, user_one, and user_two, where user_one and user_two correspond to user ids, something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE houses(
    id character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    user_one character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    user_two character varying(24) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_one) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_two) REFERENCES users(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_one, user_two)
)
```

Say I have a user with the id '123456' and he presses some button. I would like to select all user ids where '123456' is *not* a value in the user_one column of the houses table. I think this might involve a left join but I'm getting a little tripped up in terms of having one specific id (i.e. '123456') that I'd like to filter on, as opposed to just some general left join.

Edit: here's an example of what I mean:
users table:

```sql
+------------------------+
| id                     |
+------------------------+
| 123456                 | --call this row a--
| 532614                 | --call this row b--
| 549481                 | --call this row c--
| 832482                 | --call this row d--
+------------------------+
```

houses tables:

```sql
+------------------------+
| id| user_one| user_two |                   
+------------------------+
| 1 | 123456  | 532614   | -- important row --
| 2 | 549481  | 123456   |
| 3 | 532614  | 123456   |
| 4 | 549481  | 532614   |
+------------------------+
```

so, after running this query, I'd like to return row c and d from the users table, since there is a row where user_one is 123456 and user_two is 532614 (important row) in the houses table, so I want to exclude the user with the id of 532614 from my output. Also, I didn't include row a in my output because that's equal to the id 123456 itself.

Apologies if this is a basic question, I'm migrating from noSQL and am still having some difficulties grasping more complex questions like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM houses h
                  WHERE h.user_one = '123456' AND h.user_two = u.id) AND
      u.id <> '123456';
```

### Demo

If you want to use a join version, then use the following left anti-join:

```sql
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN houses h
    ON h.user_two = u.id AND h.user_one = '123456'
WHERE
    u.id <> '123456' AND
    h.id IS NULL;
```

This attempts to match each user record with a house record on the criteria that the `user_two` column matches the user, with the house's `user_one` column being `'123456'`.  It then asserts, in the `WHERE` clause, that no such match was found, indicating that the user is valid (of course we also check that the user is not `'123456'` proper as well.

Comment: this worked perfectly/was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much, I think my problem here is that I was too focused on thinking how to solve in terms of a JOIN when that wasn't even needed at all!

Comment: @Evan You can use a join, but it might be slightly more complex than using exists logic.

Comment: ah alright that makes sense, thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

please share sample data also and output you need.

I can see one issue in your query. Since you are using left outer join then user_one should not be in where clause. your query should be like this

```
select users.id from users join houses on 1 = 1 and user_one != '123456';
```